# In DDD, what is Domain?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have done 3 courses on Domain Driven Design and read quite a few articles.

These articles define *Sub-domain, Bounded Context, Ubiquitous Language*, etc... but most of them take the definition of *Domain* for granted...

The only definition that I have seen so far says domain is: Data + Behavior. Is there a better definition for *Domain*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Every software program relates to some activity or interest of its user.  That subject area to which the user applies the program is the *domain* of the software.  Some domains involve the physical world: The domain of an airline booking program involves real people getting on real aircraft.  Some domains are intangible: the domain of an accounting program is money and finance.  Software domains usually have little to do with computers, though there are exceptions: the domain of a source-code control system is software development itself.  -- Eric Evans, Domain-Driven Design.